# XSD elements with base type

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

How in XSD schema do sequence of elements with different names and one base type?

```
<function name="test">
    <set name="name" value="StackMommy" />
    <log message="hello, ${name}" />
</function>
```

I want with jaxb generated pojo classes some this:

```
class Function {
    List<Command> commands;
}
```

Comment: http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html might help.

Answer (score 2):

The `@XmlElementRef` annotation is what you are looking for in this use case.  It is used to map the concept of substitution groups.

**Function**

The `commands` property is annotated with `@XmlElementRef`.  This means we will populate this property based on the XML elements that occur that are associated with subclasses of `Command` by either `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl`.

```
package forum9952449;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
class Function {
    @XmlElementRef
    List<Command> commands;
}
```

**Command**

The `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation is used to point at the subclasses.  This is not a necessary step, but it does mean that we don't have to pass the subclasses in explicitly when we bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

```
package forum9952449;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({Set.class, Log.class})
public abstract class Command {

}
```

**Set**

We need to annotate this class with `@XmlRootElement`.  In this case the root element name defaults to `set`.

```
package forum9952449;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Set extends Command {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String value;

}
```

**Log**

Again we annotate this subclass with `@XmlRootElement`.

```
package forum9952449;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Log extends Command {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String message;

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum9952449;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Function.class);

        File xml = new File("src/forum9952449/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Function function = (Function) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(function, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Input/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<function>
    <set value="StackMommy" name="name"/>
    <log message="hello, ${name}"/>
</function>
```

**function.xsd**

The corresponding XML schema would look something like the following.  As you can start from an object model with JAXB you don't really need it.

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="function" type="function"/>

    <xs:element name="command" type="command"/>

    <xs:element name="set" type="set"
        substitutionGroup="command"/>

    <xs:element name="log" type="log"
        substitutionGroup="command"/>

    <xs:complexType name="function">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="command"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="command" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="set">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="command">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="log">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="command">
                <xs:attribute name="message"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html